# Napkin Look and Feel Error

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, look-and-feel

Please have a look at the following code

**Form.java**

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Form extends JFrame
{
    private JButton[]buttonHolder;

    public Form()
    {
        //Intializing instance variables
        buttonHolder = new JButton[9];

        this.add(createCenterPanel());
        this.setSize(300,300);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    private JPanel createCenterPanel()
    {
        JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel();
        centerPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,3,0,0));

        for(int i=0;i<9;i++)
        {
            buttonHolder[i] = new JButton();
            centerPanel.add(buttonHolder[i]);
        }

        return centerPanel;
    }
}
```

**Main.java**

```
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import napkin.NapkinLookAndFeel;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        try
        {
            Form f = new Form();
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(new NapkinLookAndFeel());
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

I am using napkin look and feel here, and I am getting the error `keys we didn't overwrite: []`. Why is this? I am not getting the GUI. Please help.

Comment: What if you swap the order of these statements (i.e. set the UIManager's look and feel _before_ instantiating the `Form` rather than afterwards).

Comment: @IanRoberts: That works for GUI display. But that doesn't take away the message. That not an exception anyway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might help

> One thing you can try is the following:
>
> - Don't set the look&feel yet.
> - Create your user interface.
> - Call setUndecorated(true) on the frame.
> - Set the look&feel.
> - Call SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI for the frame.
> - If necessary, call setUndecorated(false) on the frame.

From

http://www.coderanch.com/t/566070/GUI/java/Error-NapKin-Feel

EDIT:

The message "keys we didn't overwrite: []"
Is printed here:

```
@Override
protected void initClassDefaults(UIDefaults table) {
    super.initClassDefaults(table);
    String cName = NapkinLookAndFeel.class.getName();
    String basicPackageName = cName.replace("NapkinLookAndFeel", "Napkin");
    for (String uiType : UI_TYPES) {
        String uiClass = basicPackageName + uiType;
        table.put(uiType, uiClass);
    }

    Set<Object> keys = new HashSet<Object>(table.keySet());
    keys.removeAll(Arrays.asList(UI_TYPES));
    if (keys.size() != 0) {
        System.out.println("keys we didn't overwrite: " + keys);
    }
}
```

http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/net/sf/squirrel-sql/thirdparty-non-maven/napkinlaf/1.2/napkinlaf-1.2-sources.jar!/net/sourceforge/napkinlaf/NapkinLookAndFeel.java?format=ok

Comment: @Yohan is your app throwing some exception? Try adding `e.printStackTrace();` in your catch block.

Comment: @Pshemo:no exception. GUI works fine. Just wondering about this message

Comment: @Yohan If it is not exception I wouldn't be so worried. It is probably using console to print additional informations that can help with debugging process (if needed).

Answer (score 0):

Set the look and feel first, before you create an instance of your `Form`:

```
public static void main(String[]args)
{
    try
    {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(new NapkinLookAndFeel());
        Form f = new Form();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        // it's generally a bad idea to silently swallow exceptions,
        // you should at least do...
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```